# How to close Angular Material Sidenav with escape?

Tags: angular, angular-material

My goal is to close the [Angular Material Sidenav](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview) by pressing escape.

I have tried using the `[autoFocus]="true"` property to achieve this, but to no help.

The problem is that pressing escape has no effect - **only** if I first click inside the sidenav does pressing escape work.

I have forked one of the official examples to demonstrate [the issue here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sidenav-autofocus-bug), so you can play around with the code.

I am unsure if this is a bug with the sidenav, or just me not being able to figure out how to trap focus.

Comment: Seems to work out of the box with modes `over` and `push` https://stackblitz.com/angular/pabvpykmjoj. Only seems to be an issue with mode `'side'`.

Comment: I have checked the example, and noticed when your active element is sidenav it will close it by `esc`, Please try to click on the sidenav section anc press on the `esc`

Comment: Yes - the problem is with 'side'. @AshotAleqsanyan I know it woks by first clicking on the sidenav section and pressing esc, but thats a workaround - not a solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can have a work around with a `Hostlistener` listens `esc` key.
Like this :

```
@HostListener("document:keyup.esc")
  onkeyup() {
    console.log("close it");
    this.opened = false;
  }
```

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sidenav-autofocus-bug-25lzmd) example

Answer (score 0):

you can add a fnction like this

```
 <mat-drawer-container (keydown.escape)="drawer.closed = true"...

<mat-drawer #drawer mode="side" ...
```

this way it should close regardless of where your focus is